# How to generate the content of an href link by the return value of a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, html

I have a javascript function:

```
function foo() { return "/a/b/SomeApi"; }
```

then I have a `href` link in my web page. I want this link to point to the value returned by my javascript function, so that when the user clicks the link, it's as if the user had clicked a link with url `/a/b/SomeApi`.

I tried following:

```
<a href="javascript:foo()">Click</a>
```

But the result of this is the browser would open a new window showing the literal value `/a/b/SomeApi` instead of sending a request to the server.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why not set the href to the required value in the first place?

Comment: @RobG because the link needed to be generated dynamically. i put a fixed value here just for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think HREF was ever meant to be dynamic; for that, just use the `onclick` property, such as :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.assign(foo())">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Instead of returning the string, set the location of the current page with it, like this...</strike>

```
function foo() { document.location.href = "/a/b/SomeApi"; }
```

As pointed out by @haim770 - these are not the droids you are looking for.

If you want to specifically set the `href` attribute, you must do it from outside of the link.  Firstly you should give your link an `id` attribute, such as this...

```
<a id="myAnchor">Click</a>
```

This piece of code should then be placed either **after** the element in the page, or as part of a "document loaded" piece of code.

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "/a/b/SomeApi";
```

If you were using jQuery (which is not in your list of tags) you could do something like this...

```
$(function(){
  $("#myAnchor").attr("href", "/a/b/SomeApi")
});
```

Comment: That's not answering the question.

Comment: setting window.location.href is the right thing because everytime i click the link, the link could be different. thanks for the your suggestion anyway :)